# Current and charge as a function of time boundary conditions satisfaction in RLC AC circuit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image][image]In this derivation of current and charge as a function of time how does the books assumes the value of $\theta-\phi$ to be $-\pi/2$ , cant it have any more values as such like $\theta-\phi$ to be $-2\pi$, then also the above condition given would be satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta-\phi$ can be $\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi n$. $\phi$ is already defined. So all we are saying is that $\theta$ can be shifted by $2\pi n$, but when we put different such $\theta$ into the formula for $q(t)$, it does not change the result. The quantities being solved for, namely $q(t)$ and $i(t)$, are independent of this $2\pi n$ ambiguity. So the way the text is operating is just choose the $n=0$ case which doesn't lose any generality for the final result.